# Where are events in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, events, uiview

I learn Cocoa Touch several days, and today have stuck while looking for way to implement a custom event. Event that I can see in Connection Inspector for my UIView subclass.
What I have:
There are a UILabel and MyView:UIView on MainVindow. MyView contains a UISlider. Interfaces for Controller and MyView

```
// Controller.h 
@interface Controller : NSObject {
   IBOutlet UILabel *label;
   IBOutlet MyView *myView;
}
// I suppose that there should be something like -(IBAction) changeLabelValue for myView event
@end

// MyView.h
@interface MyView : UIView {
    IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
    float value;
}
- (IBAction) changeValue; //for slider "Changed Value" event
```

What I want:
Add something in MyView that allows it to rise a event after change *value*.
Can anybody help me? My main area in programming is .NET and I begin think that its terminology is not appropriate for this case.

Thanks.

Comment: You are right that your .NET terminology is a problem for you, as I can't understand what you are asking.  If you want to cause your IBAction to execute when your slider changes, then you just drag a connection in IB.  It is similar for text objects, but you may want to find a slightly different approach.

Comment: Ok, try to explain my scenario more clearly.
In myView I want get a native value from slider. Then after some modification (get square root e.g.) value is ready for use. Label must show this final value.
My problem is how label will know that value change. And I think implement this communication like a standard control "event" (which I can see in "Events" group of Communication Inspector for UISlider, UButton etc).
In other word -- create custom control that expand UISlider functions.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know if I'm understanding you correctly but I think what you want is responding to user events from interface components. In Cocoa the term "event" is only used for objects that describe the actual event, like a touch down or key up.

To respond to higher level events, like dragging a slider or pushing a button, Cocoa uses the target action paradigm. You set up a UI component (a `UIControl` derived view class) to send a given message to a given target whenever the component detects a change of its state.

To set the target and the action method you can use Interface Builder or the `UIControl` method `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`.